# Is the ® symbol a 3-byte or 4-byte Unicode character? How can I tell?

Tags: unicode

Is the ® symbol a 3-byte or 4-byte Unicode character? How can I tell?

Also known as \xAE

Comment: @KenWhite, “®” is not an ASCII character. And fonts have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @KenWhite pedant attack! ASCII is a 7-bit code. ® is specified as 0xae by ISO-8859-1, and as a result appears as such in the Latin MS-DOSes, Windows-1252 and most other recent western 8-bit places. But it's pedantically technically not ASCII.

Comment: @Tommy: OK. :-) Fair enough. Now go get Jukka for "ISO Larin 1" encoding. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Unicode character as such does not have any length in bytes. It is the character encoding that matters. You know the length of a character in bytes in a specific encoding from the definition of the encoding.

For example, in the ISO-8859-1 (ISO Larin 1) encoding, which encodes just a small subset of Unicode, including “®”, every character is 1 byte long.

In the UTF-16 encoding, all characters are either 2 or 4 bytes long, and characters in the range U+0000...U+FFFF, such as  “®”, are 2 bytes

In the UTF-32 encoding, all characters are 4 bytes long.

In the UTF-8 encoding, characters take 1 to 4 bytes. A simple way to check this out is to use the Fileformat.info [Character search](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm) (though this is not normative information, just a nice quick reference). E.g., the [page about U+00AE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ae/index.htm) shows the character in some encodings, including 0xC2 0xAE (that is, 2 bytes) in UTF-8.

Answer (score 5):

It is unicode number U+00AE. It's in the range [0x80, 0x7ff] so in UTF-8 it'll be encoded as two bytes — the table at the top of [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) explains in more detail*.

If you were using UTF-16 it'd also be two bytes, since no continuation is necessary.

(* my summary though: one of the features of UTF-8 is that you can jump midway into a byte stream and synchronise with the text without generating any spurious characters, because you can tell whether any byte is a continuation character without further context.

An unavoidable side effect is that only the 7-bit ASCII characters fit into a single byte and everything else takes multiple bytes. 0xae is sufficiently close to the 7-bit range to require only one extra byte. See Wikipedia for specifics.)